# Getting "ImportError: No module named parse" while trying to pip install multiparse for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install multipart and simply running the command

```
pip install multipart
```

But I am getting and error

```
 Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/cn/h4g68yd17jq5fx0cqf0fss180000gn/T/pip-install-w_zyum/multipart/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    from multipart import __version__, __author__, __license__, __doc__
  File "multipart.py", line 22, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs
ImportError: No module named parse
```

I have checked Python and PIP versions. I have Python 2.7 and 3.7 installed on the system. Doing -

```
pip3 install multipart
```

Returns -

```
Requirement already satisfied: multipart in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.2)
```

Edit - It is for a legacy work project which is in Python 2.7 and can't be updated to 3x for now.

Comment: Python 2 is EOL. You should uninstall it unless it's an inseparable part of your OS.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica it's for a legacy work project which is still in 2.7

Comment: If you need `multipart` for a Python 2 project, then why did you use `pip3` at all?

Comment: `pip3` installs packages specifically for Python3... you'd better use `pip2` for your task. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica because I have multiple projects in both Python 2 and 3. I wanted to check if same package installation in python 3 gives any issue or if there is any issue in my python or pip paths. Moreover, I am aware that the import error No module named parse occurs because urllib.parse has been replaced by urlparse in python3. But this error in my case is not occurring in a piece of code I wrote, it is in a line in python2's multipart library.

Comment: @s.k Yes I know that very well, I have used pip which is pip2 by default in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multipart 0.2 is available for python 3 only.

for python 2.7 you can install multipart version 0.1 by

`pip install multipart==0.1`

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I am curious to why pip for python 2 was trying to install a version of multipart that's not available to it.

Comment: pip has two methods for installation either by using *.whl file or from source. For multipart 0.2 *.whl for python 3 only is available. Hence it tried to compile from source for python 2 and failed.